# Is the following generalization of piecewise continuity equivalent to any other common types of functions on metric spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, continuity

EDIT: I think what I have isn't precisely what I want... we should also require $x$ in condition (3) to be "not bad" in some sense, although I'm not quite sure what that should mean for my purposes, yet. For now, let's use the new (3).

I have a condition on functions $f:X\to Y$ between metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, let's call it "tree continuity", which is defined as follows:

> There is a (possibly infinite) rooted tree $T$ with root $r$ and a "labelling" function $\Gamma:T\to\tau$ (where $\tau$ is the set of open subsets of $X$) such that
>
> 1. $\Gamma(r)$ is dense in $X$
> 2. For any $t\in T$ the union $\cup_{s\in Child(t)}\Gamma(s)$ is dense in $\Gamma(t)$ where $Child(t)$ is the set of children of $t$
> 3. Any sequence converging to some $x$ in the intersection of the closures of all the $\Gamma(t)$ over all $t$ in some maximal branch $B$ of $T$ is convergent.
>
> OLD 3. (IGNORE - SEE EDIT) For any maximal branch $B\subset T$, if $x_i\to x$ in $X$ and for any $t\in B$ there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $n\geq N\implies x_n\in\Gamma(t)$, then $f(x_i)\to f(x)$.

**Is the above condition equivalent to any other well-known "types" of functions on metric spaces?**

I'd try to figure this out myself, but I'm not too familiar with the "standard" sort of functions one would consider, and I don't know how to approach this any better than just tediously checking counterexamples for each of the dozens of different types of types of functions one might want to consider on metric spaces.

### Progress so far

It is easy to see that not all tree continuous functions are continuous: simply note that being continuous on an open, dense subset is enough to be tree continuous, and that this is strictly weaker than continuity.

Also, while it is more involved, it is still easy to see that not every function is tree continuous. For this, simply have $X,Y=[0,1]$ and take a maximal branch $B=\{t_1,t_2,\ldots\}$ (where each $t_i$ is the parent of $t_{i+1}$) using the axiom of choice, then consider the intersection over all $t_i$ of the closure of $\Gamma(t_i)$. Since this is the intersection along some closed sets $\overline{\Gamma(t_1)}\supset\overline{\Gamma(t_2)}\supset\overline{\Gamma(t_3)}\supset\cdots$, it is nonempty by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Now let $x$ be an element of the above intersection of closures. It is easy to see that either all monotone increasing sequences or all monotone decreasing sequences converging to $x_i$ are eventually in any $\Gamma(t_n)$. Thus, if $x_i$ is monotone increasing (decreasing) and converging to $x$, then $f(x_i)$ must converge to $f(x)$. Not all functions from $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ have a point $x$ with this property (consider the indicator function of the rationals, for example), so not all functions are tree continuous.

This narrows it down to being somewhere in between "continuous somewhere" and "continuous everywhere", but I wonder if there's a property of subsets of metric spaces so that the above is equivalent to "continuous on a set with this property"? Or perhaps there is a more general property that the above is continuous to?

Comment: Is continuity on a dense $G_\delta$ set also enough to get tree continuity?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Good question! Any reason to suspect one answer or the other?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti You made me realize my definition was slightly wrong - I think with the new one it should be!

Comment: In fact, I think this is an equivalence, this might be just what I'm looking for! Any references you could point me to about continuity on dense G_delta sets?

Comment: I don't quite understand New 3: "any convergent sequence... is convergent".

Comment: My bad: should say that for any such sequence f(x_i) converges to f(x)... I’ll fix it when I get the chance